# Webform get all submission for a node by date

Tags: webforms

I am using webform_get_submissions to get all submissions, I have a requirements to get only one day back submissions.

Is there any way to get this results?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not possible directly. See [webform_get_submissions date range filter](https://www.drupal.org/node/1147898) issue.

From taht issue:

> We now have built-in range functionality in #1237660: Add date range
>   or "last X submissions" to CSV/Excel download. That patch just uses
>   the existing ability of webform_get_submissions() to filter by SIDs,
>   which would probably work in your situation too as long as you can
>   retrieve a list of SIDs by date.

So you have to build a query to retrieve a list of SID's bty date and then pass it to webform_get_submissions.